# how to remove / hide price from woocommerce WordPress template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently doing a website for my friend and I don't have much coding experience, the website is meant to be a wholesalers cash and carry. 
`http://www.abdfoods.com`
What he has asked me for is a cart based website, and this template i have used it's doing the job properly apart from he **Wants to remove the prices from the website as prices change everyday they would like people to make orders without prices**

I found some codes from online that i have used already it has removed the prices from the shop page but i would like prices to be removed from all pages such as **Home Page, Cart etc...**

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
```

Comment: You can do this with CSS, but you have the site under construction. Open it up and I can point the selectors your need.

Comment: @ham-sandwich i have just allowed the website for public

Comment: How can i hide the pricing by css? @ham-sandwich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the filters you applied worked, but you would place the following CSS into your themes style.css to override the template's custom functionality.

**Cart**

```
#cart > a > span.amount {
    display: none;
}
```

**Sidebar**

```
div.deals-information > div.price{
    display: none;
}
```

**Individual Product**

```
div.widget.widget-products.products > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.col-md-4.col-sm-12.shopcol.last.wow.fadeInUp.product-wrapper > div > div > div > div.price{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Where does the code go the the individual product as i don't have any files by that name.

Comment: Just in your themes css file

Comment: Note that the prices are still visible if anyone inspects the source code! Some clients want to have their prices to be a secret.